# Efficient query for the join and case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I  have 3 tables in SQL server and I am trying to frame a query to get the following:

avg amount per customer for a particular `product_id` (say  1) and 0 when a customer didn't purchase the product

Here is the format for 3 sample tables

```
create table #person (id int, name varchar(10))
create table #sales (cust_id int, product_id int, amount int)
create table #product (product_id int , prodcut varchar(10))
```

This is what I tried so far but I am looking for a more efficient way

```sql
    with CTE as (
select cust_id, product_id,
case when product_id=1 then avg(amount) else 0 end  as am
from #person left join  #sales on #sales.cust_id=id --and #sales.product_id=1
group by cust_id,product_id )
select max(am)  from CTE group by cust_id
```

The result I am looking for :

customer 1|$avg

customer 2| 0

customer  |0

Assuming only customer 1 bought product 1 and all the others didn't

Comment: left join, group by etc

Comment: You should show us an attempt of what you tried, and where you're stuck.

Comment: @pwilcox updated!

Answer (score 0):

1. group by + avg() on join between #person and #sales, no outer join here
2. outer join the result of step 1 with #product join #person

```sql
select p.name, p.product, isnull(q.avg, 0) avg 
from (
  select cust_id, product_id, avg(amount) avg 
  from #sales 
  group by cust_id, product_id
) q
  right join (
    select pr.*, pe.* 
    from #product pr 
      cross apply #person pe
  ) p on p.id = q.cust_id and p.product_id = q.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.id, c.name, p.product, coalesce(avg(s.amount),0)
  from #person c
    left outer join #sales s
      on s.cust_id = c.id
      where s.product_id = @product_id_parameter
    left join #product p
      on s.product_id = p.product_id
    group by c.id
```

The `left outer join` gives you an empty sales record (full of NULLs) for customers who didn't buy the product. `AVG()` of a NULL is NULL, and `COALESCE` gives you the first non-NULL argument, so you get either the average (if there are sales for that customer) or zero (if not).

You don't need to make a `distinct` because the `group by` clause already reduces you to one output row per customer.

Finally, I'm assuming you've got a variable called `@product_id_parameter` that is the Product ID you're looking for, as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close to the solution. You need to `left join` `person` and `sales` indeed and you need the match you specified and `product_id` comparison there as well. For each record we have `amount` if the `join` yielded a match and 0 otherwise. This is how the records are grouped and at the end we select the average.

```
select cust_id, 
avg(isnull(amount, 0)) as am
from person left join  sales on sales.cust_id=id and sales.product_id=1
group by cust_id
```

Comment: the case portion of your solution does not look like valid TSQL.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits thanks, that was a typo, my point was that case is overcomplication in this ... case.

Comment: @LajosArpad thanks for the input. This is what i ended up with :                  
   with CTE as (
select cust_id, product_id,
case when product_id=1 then avg(amount) else 0 end  as am
from #person left join  #sales on #sales.cust_id=id --and #sales.product_id=1
group by cust_id,product_id )
select max(am)  from CTE group by cust_id

Comment: @sav you are welcome. If any of the answers was correct, then you might consider marking them as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would format your query as the following:

```sql
select distinct cust_id, 
    avg(case when #sales.product_id=1 then amount end)
from #person left join  #sales on #sales.cust_id=id 
group by cust_id, #sales.product_id
```

This way, you'll only be getting the average values when the product id is 1, rather than getting average of everything. I'm unsure of your full goal, but this seems to hit your needs.

Comment: Hi , please see the updated question for the result I am trying to get. Thanks for the help!